# Cookies sticking to plate

Tags: baking, cookies

After I bake cookies I let them cool on the pan for 3-5 minutes then move them to a plate.

However I have noticed the next day the cookies on the bottom stick to the plate, then break into small pieces if I try to remove them.

What should I do different so the bottom cookies do not stick to the plate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to let them cool completely on a wire rack before moving them to a plate or sealed container.

This will prevent the starch on the bottoms from steaming onto the plate.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to a wire rack is to simply turn them upside down.  The bottoms need exposure to the air to cool and dry - against a plate (or the pan) they sweat leftover moisture from the baking, which a cooling rack is supposed to prevent.  However, the important bit seems to be cooling the undersides - so if you don't have a rack, even just flipping them on the baking sheet helps tremendously.  I suspect it's because the cookie tops dry a bit more in baking, and the undersides are a bit more porous.  They can then be moved to a plate or container at your convenience.

Comment: also the bottoms are flat (from contact with the baking sheet) while the tops are likely to be rounded, ridged, and otherwise nonflat, meaning less contact with the surface.